# Using either javascript to target sibling elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I been stuck on this for a full afternoon now.

So I have a webshop that displays a product list, rather than post the code here, I will do it conceptually, to simplify the problem. Hoping someone could point me in the right direction.

I have a list of div classes like the following:

```
<div class="product-container">
    <div class="product-price">Price info</div>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
    <div class="product-price">Price info</div>
    <div class="production-options">
        <select id="selectoptions1" name="product1" class="attribute_list">
          <option value="Colour (please select)">Colour (please select)</option>
          <option value="White">White</option>
          <option value="Navy Blue">Navy Blue</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="product-container">
    <div class="product-price">Price info</div>
</div>
```

You will notice that the middle container has a child class `production-options`. I want to write a JS function that will detect whether a product-container has a child called `product-options`, If there is, then set the padding of `product-price` to 20px or whatever.

So javascript would look like this.

```
if($( ".product-options")) {
    $( ".product-price" ).css( "padding-top", "20px" );
}
```

Now this will affect all the elements with class name `product-price`, how do I make it so that it will only affect the class `product-price` with a sibling `product-options`? (using ID's is not an option, as these are custom fields/attributes generated by virtuemart).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a combination of [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [next](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

```
$( ".product-price" ).filter(function() {
    return $(this).next(".production-options").length;
});
```

`filter` will ensure only `product-price` elements matching the criteria are returned. `next` will ensure the next sibling in the DOM has a class `production-options`. If the `product-price` can be anywhere (not just directly next) you can use the [siblings](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) selector instead:

```
$( ".product-price" ).filter(function() {
    return $(this).siblings(".production-options").length;
});
```

Comment: thanx! i appreciate the explanation, i was lost for a while...but this is exactly what i needed! good explanation. In fact they all are :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code:

```
$.each($('.product-container'), function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if($this.find( ".product-options").length) {
         $this.find('.product-price').css( "padding-top", "20px" );
    }
});
```

Comment: `if($(this).find( ".product-options"))` is always true.

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution sis to target the `production-options` element then find the previous `product-price` element

```
$('.production-options').prev('.product-price').css( "padding-top", "20px" );
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/wspY8/)

Answer (score 1):

Use `.parents` to select the parent.

```
$(".production-options").parents(".product-container");
```

Use `.prev` to directly select `.product-price`

```
$(".production-options").prev(".product-price");
```